Using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 23.4.0 to connect to Oracle 11
The official Oracle NuGet Package (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) recently updated to 23.4.0.
Before, i used version 3.21.140 and everything went fine. Now, i have an ORA-28040 issue.
I use Oracle Client 11.
My App.config file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> 
    <connectionStrings>     
        <add name="MY_DB" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my.db.host)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=my.db.service.name))); User Id=my_db_user;Password=my_db_pwd; Enlist=False;"/>
    </connectionStrings>

The function to connect Oracle DB
Public Function OpenOracleConnexion() As Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    DebugManager(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString, blnTextualDebugActive, True, blnVisualDebugActive)
    Dim strMsgCriticalException As String = "Problème de connexion aux bases Oracles. " & strMsgErrorTellYourAdmin & vbCrLf & "-- Message d'erreur: "

    Try
        If cnxBase.State = 1 Then
            cnxBase.Close()
        End If
        cnxBase.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MY_DB").ConnectionString
        cnxBase.Open()
        Return cnxBase
        Exit Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(strMsgCriticalException & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, strMsgBoxGeneralErrorTitle)
        Return Nothing
        Exit Try

    End Try

    DebugManager(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString, blnTextualDebugActive, False, blnVisualDebugActive)
End Function

